# Counter of arguments and ifnum

Tags: macros

Why is this `ifnum` always true? `\@tempcntb` is 5, shouldn't it instead print `\tmp` for the last argument? Also, I don't understand what `m@ne` does, because this certainly doesn't advance the counter by 1 (It's going from outside to inside the nested `\tmp`'s)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\metafunc[1]{{
\count@\z@
Number of arguments: \the\@tempcntb \par
\@tempcnta\z@\relax
\@tempcntb=\count@
\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\advance\count@\@ne}
\ifnum\@tempcnta=\@tempcntb
    \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    \textcolor[RGB]{\the\numexpr255*\@tempcnta/(\count@)\relax,
                 0,
                 \the\numexpr255-(255*\@tempcnta/(\count@))\relax}%
                {\tmp(}}\relax
    \@tempcnta\count@ 
    \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \textcolor[RGB]{\the\numexpr255*\@tempcnta/(\count@)\relax,
                 0,
                 \the\numexpr255-(255*\@tempcnta/(\count@))\relax}%
                {)}\relax
    \advance\@tempcnta\m@ne
}
\else
\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\tmp}
\fi
}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\metafunc{Banana,Stool,Another banana,chair,peanut}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@tempcntb` is a counter register name; by using `\def` you destroy its nature (and you tell TeX to use the current value of `\count@` at expansion time, not at definition time); do `\@tempcntb=\@count@` for giving the counter the current value of `\count@`.

Comment: @egreg Doing so changed the output from 5 arguments to an empty space in the `Total counted number of arguments: \@tempcntb \par`.

Comment: For *printing* the decimal representation of the counter's value you have to say `\the\@tempcntb`

Comment: @egreg The new code yields errors and `\the\@tempcntb` yields 0 after declaring the `\@...` register values and 223 before (where did that number come from?), see updated OP.

Comment: Ist `\@tempcntb=\@count@` a typing error perchance?

Comment: Also, everything seems to be in reverse order. `\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\advance\count@\@ne}` counts the arguments, so it should stand before reporting the number of arguments, shouldn't it?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yes, it should be `\@tempcntb=\count@`

Comment: @1010011010 I fixed the typo; but setting `\@tempcntb=\count@` in that position is of course wrong.

Comment: Also, the `\ifnum` is not inside of any `\@for` construct, so it cannot be used to refer to the position of one specific argument.

Comment: I think you should start experimenting with a much simpler construct and work out a thorough understanding of `\@for` for yourself. At the moment your code is a bit of a jumble.

Comment: @1010011010 It's really unclear what you want to do with the `\ifnum` which will always be false, unless the number of arguments is zero.

Comment: @egreg @StephanLehmke I am trying to get the last output to be `\tmp` (the one nested into all the other ones)

Comment: @1010011010 In the other thread I have added a change that does what you seems to be looking for.

Comment: Pointless thread, just release it from its misery already :-)